# Diferencia entre querySelector, querySelectorAll, getElementbyId, getElementbyTag

Tags: javascript, html

Quisiera si alguien me podria explicar bien sencillo cuales son las diferencias entre estos 'selectores' ya que me esta costando entederlos!
Sobre todo entre los querys y los get element. 
Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Funciones Base

#### `querySelector`:

Retorna **el primer elemento** que cumpla con el criterio dado. Puede ser invocada sobre el `document` o sobre algún elemento. En caso de usarse sobre un elemento, las búsqueda se limita a los hijos de ese elemento.

Si la búsqueda no encuentra nada, retorna `null`.

#### `querySelectorAll`

Retorna **todos los elementos** que cumplan con el criterio dado. Al igual que `querySelector` puede ser invocada sobre el `document` o sobre algún elemento. Siempre retorna un `NodeList`, el cual no es una array con todas las de la ley (map, reduce, indexOf, etc), pero pude convertirse en uno, con facilidad.

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("div"))
```

Si no encuentra elementos que cumplan el criterio, retorna un NodeList sin elementos, nunca retorna `null`.

### Funciones especializadas

#### `getElementById`

Retorna el primer elemento con el `id` especificado, es en muchos sentidos equivalente a hacer, `querySelector('#elId')`. Osea que retorna `null` si no hay elementos con dicho Id.

#### `getElementByTagName`

Retorna todos los elementos cuyo con el nombre de tag especificado, es en muchos sentidos equivalente a hacer, `querySelectorAll('div')` (si buscaras `<div/>`). Osea que retorna un `NodeList` vacío si no hay nada que cumpla las condiciones.

Por ultimo, existe este otro.

#### `getElementByClassName`

Retorna todos los elementos que mencionen la clase especificada, es en muchos sentidos equivalente a hacer, `querySelectorAll('.clase')`. Tambien retorna un `NodeList`, mismas reglas.

### NodeList dinámicos:

Otra diferencia **muy importante** es que un NodeList resultado de `getElementsByTagName` y `getElementsByClassName` **son dinámicos**, es decir que si luego de hacer ejecutado query, se agrega un nodo al DOM que cumpla el criterio, este aparece en el `NodeList` **sin necesidad de repetir la consulta**. Esta es una diferencia muy importante frente a `querySelectorAll`.

```js
var nodelist = document.querySelectorAll('.a');
var nodelist2 = document.getElementsByClassName('a');

function agregarOtroDiv() {
   var e = document.createElement('div');
   e.className="a"
   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(e);
   console.log(nodelist.length);
   console.log(nodelist2.length);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="agregarOtroDiv()">agregar div</button>
<div class="a"></div><div class="a"></div><div class="a"></div><div class="a"></div>
```

### Performance

Las funciones especializadas son mas eficientes, se han hecho pruebas de performance y en el mejor de los casos pueden llegar a superar varias veces la velocidad de `querySelector` y `querySelectorAll`. Pero esto es bastante variable y depende de la implementación.

Answer (score 4):

para el siguiente HTML

```
<html>
  <p id="elemento1" class="clase1">Hola mundo</p>
  <p class="clase1" >hola mundo2</p>
</html>
```

**QuerySelector**: Selecciona el primer elemento que coincide con la consulta.

Ejemplo: `document.querySelector('.clase1').innerHTML // hola mundo`

**QuerySelectorAll**: selecciona todas las coincidencias y las retorna en un array

Ejemplo:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.clase1')[0].innerHTML // hola mundo
document.querySelectorAll('.clase1')[1].innerHTML // hola mundo2
```

**getElementById**: selecciona el primer elemento que contenga como id el valor indicado.

Ejemplo: `document.getElementById('elemento1').innerHTML // hola mundo`

getElementByTag  no existe, peor si existe getElementByTagName

**getElementByTagName:** obtiene todos los elementos que coinciden con la consulta, pero solo se permiten etiquetas html: p,b,div,li...etc

ejemplo:

```
document.querySelectorAll('p')[0].innerHTML // hola mundo
document.querySelectorAll('p')[1].innerHTML // hola mundo2
```

Comment: mil gracias por la ayuda!!!! me ha servido muchisimo!